# Unordered list is aligned left and with huge space between bullet and test

Tags: html, css, html-lists, jekyll, github-pages

I'm starting with CSS and jekyll/github-pages. I cloned some jekyll template https://github.com/volny/stylish-portfolio-jekyll and I'm trying to modify the about.html file from it to add unordered list like:

```
    <section id="about" class="about">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2>XXXXXX</h2>
              <ul>
                <li>aaaaaaa</li>
                <li>bbbbbbbbbb</li>
                <li>ccccccccc</li>
                <li>dddddddd</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </section>
```

But the result is not as expected, there is huge gap between bullet and text, bullet is left aligned and text is centered.

[image: wrong align]

I'd like the bullet to be next to text and with some small padding on the left.

Which file to take a look on?

Comment: Include your CSS in the post please. see how to create a [mcve]

Comment: will do, but which one?

Comment: which one what? give us a [mcve]. we shouldn't have to go to github, find your CSS, and extract the relevant parts just to reproduce this layout from a small block of html.

Comment: hey, which one file, there's 3 of them and one has 6585 lines, should I really add such a huge file to this quesiton? I'm new to css and you could at least point me which part is relevant for it.

Comment: I'm not going to go to your project and do that for you - you need to do that for us. And don't include 6585 lines. That wouldn't be "minimal" would it? *"Minimal – Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem"*

Answer (score 1):

Add list-style-position: inside to the ul element.
The default value for the list-style-position property is outside.

```
ul {
    text-align: center;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

Another option that gives a different result is to center the ul element

```
.parent {
      text-align: center;
    }
.parent > ul {
      display: inline-block;
    }

<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```